# du (disk usage) reports 6.1M but directory is empty

Tags: disk-usage

This does not make any sense!

```
user@localhost:~/folder$ du -h --max-depth=1
6.1M    ./subfolder
6.1M    .
user@localhost:~/folder$ ls -la subfolder
total 6228
drwx------ 2 user user 6369280 2013-07-08 16:03 .
drwx------ 9 user user    4096 2013-07-08 16:04 ..
```

`du` reports 6.1 megabytes, `ls` reports a total of "6228" (I don't know total of what)... but the folder is empty... indeed, there is no file there and it should be empty indeed.

Why is that? Can someone explain this to me?

This is happening in a VPS running Ubuntu 10.04

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking at a result of how Ext2/3/4 filesystems work. The list of files (inodes) in the directory is kept as the directory 'file', represented as the `.` in the listing. After removing the files in the directory, the disk usage does not shrink.

Therefore, I assume you had a lot of files in the directory before (or you're omitting them in the `ls` output in your question). The only solution is to remove and recreate the directory to free up this space.

See also: [Why could the size of the “dot file” /. exceed 4096?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56284/23363)

For as to what the `total 6228` means, see [ls command: what does the first line mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4109/23363)

Comment: Wow... I only read this answer 6 years after making the question, even though it has been posted only 30 minutes after I've made the question.

Better late than never.

Thanks, @gertvdijk

Answer (score 0):

Youn can use this command to see the size of hidden folders
This command sorts the content including hidden files in human readable format of the current directory.

```
du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h
```